# Magento 2.4.3: Cart products not showing

Tags: cart, magento2.4.3

So I'm facing this issue in my DEV environment. When I add a product to the cart it shows correctly on the mini cart but when I go to the cart editing page it shows an empty list.

I don't have any custom code for this page /Block and it all worked well on Magento version 2.4.1. Is anyone facing the same issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more info, try:

- switching back to Luma and recheck if it works or not.
- Also try disabling all non-stock modules.

This should give you enough information to debug it. (You can also add the results here, so we have more information to assist)

Comment: Done as you asked. The problem seems to be here, it is returning an empty string for the generated html. I'm trying to findout wich renderer is being called

\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart.php
public function getItemHtml(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item)
    {
        $renderer = $this->getItemRenderer($item->getProductType())->setItem($item);
        return $renderer->toHtml();
    }

Comment: Just found out the problem, I had an empty default.phtml that was overriding the one used for item sin cart. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help and glad it is fixed! :)